# Show $z_\alpha = -z_\alpha$.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and the standard normal upper quantile $z_\alpha = \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)$ I need to show that $$ z_\alpha=-z_\alpha$$
The hint given was to use the fact that the density function ($\phi$) is an even function and show $\Phi(x)=1-\Phi(-x)$.

Showing that was not too difficult:
$$\begin{align*}
\Phi(x)=&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)dx -\int_{x}^{\infty}\phi(x)dx\\
=&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)dx -\int_{-\infty}^{-x}\phi(x)dx\quad\text{because $\phi$ is even}\\
=& 1-\Phi(-x)
\end{align*}
$$

The next hint was to now substitute $x$ for $z$ but I do not see how to arrive at $ z_\alpha=-z_\alpha$

The only other conclusions I came to is that $\Phi(z_\alpha) = 1-\alpha $ an then $\Phi(-z_\alpha )=\alpha$?

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Edit:

I realized substituting it into what was proven does show something that is:

$\Phi(z_\alpha) = 1-\Phi(-z_\alpha)$ which gives us  $1-\alpha = 1-\alpha$

But that did not really achieve any result.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question has a typo; as it stands, they are asking you to show $z_\alpha = 0$ which is absurd. I think they meant $z_\alpha = -z_{1-\alpha}$.

Comment: Well that would explain why I am having such a hard time with it, I will ask my professor and update the post.

Comment: @angryavian I am going to assume this is a typo but that still does not really give me any insight on how to get to the final step. What should I do from here, if you do not mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the problem is asking you to show $z_\alpha = -z_{1-\alpha}$:

- By the definition of $z_\alpha$ and $z_{1-\alpha}$, you have $\Phi(z_{1-\alpha}) = \alpha$ and $\Phi(z_\alpha) = 1-\alpha$.
- By the work that you have done,  you have $\Phi(z_{1-\alpha}) = 1 - \Phi(-z_{1-\alpha})$.
- Thus $\Phi(-z_{1-\alpha}) = 1-\alpha$, and finally $-z_{1-\alpha} = z_\alpha$.

Comment: I thought by definition $z_\alpha = \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)$ so would that not make $\Phi(z_\alpha) = 1-\alpha$?

Comment: @Trap.Lord Sorry, fixed my typos.

Comment: I appreciate all your support!